# F# keyDown how to get the pressed key

Tags: forms, button, f#, key, sudoku

In my current Project which is a graphical sudoku game I have created a board of buttons, when you click the button it is marked. After marking a button you should be able to press a number on the keyboard and that number (0..9) should be retrieved (0 if you press 0, 1 if you press 1 etc.).

So my question is: How can I get which keyboard key the user pressed, and if it's a number then retrieve it so that I can put it in the 2d array and show it as text in the marked button?

I include a part of my program (which is good to compile if you get the Fsharpx, System.Forms, System.Drawing and other necessary libraries) so that you can see how I've thought so far.

```
namespace Sudoku
open FSharp.Control.Observable 

module Main =

    open System.Windows.Forms
    open System.Drawing

    let sudokuGame = Array2D.init 9 9 (fun x y -> 0)

    let form = new Form(Text="Sudoku game", TopMost=true, Width=360, Height=390)

    let buttonPos text x y = 
        let defaultSize = new Size(30,30) in
            (new Button(Text=text, Top=x, Left=y, Size=defaultSize, BackColor=Color.Aqua)) :> Control

    let gameButtons = [|for y in 1..9 do for x in 1..9 -> (buttonPos "0" (x*30) (y*30))|]

    let changeText pos c = (Array.get (gameButtons) (pos)).Text <- c

    form.Controls.AddRange gameButtons

    let rec obsMerger obsList =
            match obsList with
            | x1::[] -> x1
            | x1::xs -> Observable.merge x1 (obsMerger xs)
            | [] -> failwith "No Observables"

    let obsList = [for x in 81..(161) -> Observable.map(fun _ -> x) (gameButtons.[x-81].KeyDown)] @ [ for x in 0..80 ->  (Observable.map (fun _-> x) ((Array.get(gameButtons)(x)).Click)) ]

    let playModeObservables = obsMerger obsList 

    let rec playMode observable gameField lastPressed = async{

            let! somethingObservable = Async.AwaitObservable(observable) 

            match somethingObservable with
            | x     when x < 81 && x > -1  ->   return!  playMode observable gameField x
            | x     when x > 80 && x < 162 ->   changeText lastPressed ((x-80).ToString())
                                                return!  playMode observable gameField (x-81)
            | _                            ->   failwith "Shoot" 
        } 

    Async.StartImmediate(playMode playModeObservables sudokuGame 0) ; System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(form)
```

Comment: Use they keydown event:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I have an observable monitoring keyDown events and I can obviously get them since when I press a key I can change the content in the button. The main problem I'm having is that I can't seem to find (not even in msdn) how to get which key was pressed and how to determine from that key which value was inserted by the user.

Comment: Did you see the C# example on the linked page, that code is pretty easy to translate to F#

Comment: I try to use the c# example to get it working but it's no good so far. I think I know how the keyEventArgs work what I can't see is how I can create one that reads the keyboard and that can be checked against with for example "if e.KeyCode >= Keys.D0 || e.KeyCode <= Keys.D9 then .. do stuff ... else ..." How can I create an e? Tried with "let a = new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs()" but it needs some key for argument and I'd like to take in a key from the user.

Comment: You don't "create" the event args, they are passed to your event handler as the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @johnpalmer who showed me [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) site, and because an example from [this site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30414/Getting-Started-in-F-A-Windows-Forms-Application) and @fyodorsoikin (who pointed me the right way) I were able to solve the question.

To get keys you need a KeyEventHandler which needs a function which it will call when a key is struck. In this function you can check additional stuff and do the things you need to do.

Ex:

```
let stuffToDoWhenKeyPressed s (e : KeyEventArgs) = 
        match e with
        | e when e.KeyCode = Keys.D0 -> gameButtons.[0].Text <- "0"
        | e when e.KeyCode = Keys.D1 -> gameButtons.[0].Text <- "1" 
        | _  -> GUI.Play.gameButtons.[0].Text <- "?" 

gameButtons.[0].KeyDown.AddHandler(new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler (fun s e -> stuffToDoWhenKeyPressed s e ))
```

Comment: you can make a bit easier: KeyDown.AddHandler(stuffToDoWhenKeyPressed) and in function stuffToDoWhenKeyPressed can change gameButtons.[0].Text on (s :?> Button).Text ....And but why only 1 button handled?

Comment: Aha thanks will try that out! :) I did that since I just learned how it should be done, now I will try to make it work for all buttons. The only problem now is how to update the text in a "general button" with the value of the key pressed.

Comment: approximately so: http://pastebin.com/aRw7yRaX I think for such a question is more suitable chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f